# Does a dynamodb GetItem request that doesn't return any data consume read provisioning?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, provisioning

If a GetItem request to dynamoDB resulted in no entries for the corresponding Hash Key/Range Key, does it still count toward the allowed number of provisioned table reads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, DynamoDB does consume the provisioned read throughput.

> If you perform a read operation on an item that does not exist,
>   DynamoDB will still consume provisioned read throughput: A strongly
>   consistent read request consumes one read capacity unit, while an
>   eventually consistent read request consumes 0.5 of a read capacity
>   unit.

[CapacityUnitCalculations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithTables.html#CapacityUnitCalculations)